# How to constrain a neural network to be commutative in its inputs?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning

What is the most general way to constrain a neural network to be commutative with respect to its inputs?

The learned network function: f(.,.)

Commutative: f(a,b) = f(b,a)

"most general": can represent the widest class of commutative functions

I'm not sure how to make that totally precise, but maybe something theoretical can be constructed out of some composition of universal approximators and some fixed commutative function...

Comment: Just a thought: If you train any network with all data duplicated to reflect the commutativity, what would happen?

Comment: Doing data augmentation is one engineering solution to the problem, but you end up with something that is not commutative.

Comment: It should be near-commutatitve, so maybe taking an average of $(f(a,b) + f(b,a))/2$ as the prediction might work out? That's what you do in numerical analysis sometimes.

Comment: That's an idea I had too... you can tack another general function on after the mean, which probably makes it more general. A downside is that it doesn't extend well to many inputs.

Comment: Well, you'll need $\frac1{k!} \sum_{\sigma \in S_k} f(x_{\sigma})$ where $(x_\sigma)_i = x_{\sigma(i)}$ for input vector $x$ and permutation $\sigma$. This'll be okay for 3 or 4 inputs.

Comment: Another easily generalizable idea would be to sort the inputs before feeding them into the NN (also during training). This essentially means you constrain the input space to $a \le b$.